# Is the following complex value differential equation always has a solution?

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $a(z)$ be a fixed complex value complex variable function, not necessarily holomorphic. Consider the following differential equation
$$
\frac{\overline{\partial}f}{\partial \overline{z}}+af=0.
$$
Is it true that for any $a$, this equation always (locally) has a non-zero solution? If not, could we find an $a(z)$ such that it has only zero as its solution?

Comment: I would start by looking for $f$ in the form $f = e^g$. The equation becomes $g_{\bar z} = -a$. Then take the Cauchy transform of $-a$.